# log every linux command line ever used?

Tags: linux, shell

so, I'm solid on linux basics, and have never written a shell script.  But there is something I would like to get, or do.

Would it be possible to have linux log ALL COMMANDS I EVER TYPE in a single file?  I.e., every ls -l and cd /this/folder etc., but also the install records I have done and more.

If this file exists great.  If there is a persistent file created for EACH session and user, then maybe I can write a script to conjoin the lines.  Or, what other options are available?

I'd like the file to have 3 columns, user executing, datetime executed, and copy of the command string.  Some kind of results or error if returned would be great.  MANY THANKS from a guy who is amazed what Linux is capable of doing!

Comment: Why do you ask? Maybe you want process accounting, see [acct(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5.html)

Comment: With all due respect, that's not it.  That accounts for processes after they terminate.  I am looking for something that accounts for Command Line entries and the time they were executed; and which goes back to the day the server was born if I need to check it.  It looks like we may write this ourselves and I will share it with folks when it is done.

Comment: oh, this is similar to apache weblogs in concept

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running bash, look at your `~/.bash_history file`.

Comment: This is not a full answer. Also know that by default the bash_history has an offset limit and doesn't log endlessly.

Comment: @Allendar: No, it's not; but it's a good one. It shows that the OP didn't look very far before he asked here, or at least didn't tell us why that wouldn't work. With a little tweaking (HISTFILESIZE, HISTTIMEFORMAT, histappend) it would probably do.

Comment: I actually did look (this was about 3 weeks back) but my understanding was that .bash_history logged for that session only.  Sometimes you get a wrong answer or resource...  anyway, this is a good answer and I appreciate it.  SOOOOO... I could write a cron job that would pull from each user's history, add a timestamp (though it wouldn't of course be exact), and store the command, the user, and the timestamp in a persistent file or database.  I just wondered if there were other feaures like that already in place.